# Is it possible or recommended to make the central repository as bare repository when git-flow initiated

Tags: git, version-control, git-flow

We're planning to have a git-flow to our projects. The git-flow will contains master branch (production), develop branch (staging) and feature branch (for tasks/bug fixes).

Master and develop branch shouldn't be able to commit and can only pull files, by doing so, we ended up agreeing to make the master and develop branch a bare repository.

Is it possible to make the master and develop branch a bare repository when git-flow initiated? If so, is there a cons and pros if we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing concepts.

You don't make branches into bare repositories. Branches exist within a repository (independently of it being bare or not).

If you want to enforce git-flow and prevent direct commits to the develop and master branches, you need to use a git-repository-management-software that supports such feature. Many free and commercial options are available. Three of the most used ones are github, gitlab and bitbucket. There you can configure your server to only allow changes to develop and master via pull requests.

If you want to help newcomers to git by using local scripts you could also do it, but I'm not sure it's worth the hassle, just rely on your repo management software.

Bare repositories are used for specific use cases, but in normal development, you wouldn't use them.

As you pointed out in the question, a bare repo would be good as a "central" repository.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @a-m. I haven't actually used bare repository before and one of our collegue suggested to make them bare repository. May I ask to which case do you usually use bare repository? We don't use git-repository-management-software to some of our projects. Do you think that it would be better to use it to all of our projects? There are also instance that we can't have the files uploaded in any repository management system due to confidentiality reason.

Comment: You use bare repositories when you won't be editing your files directly there, so they make good "remote" repos. However I'd still prefer to use a repo management software instead, which will provide extra features, such as user management, security, etc. One of the three I posted above has a free on-prem solution.

Comment: Thank you @a-m... I'll do more research regarding the bare repositories and the extra features that the git-repository-management-software has. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you really don't want to try a repo management software and want to manage them yourself, you might find these [gitflow hooks](https://github.com/jaspernbrouwer/git-flow-hooks) useful. Note that I haven't tested them, as I'd recommend the other approach.

Comment: Welcome. Hope you find a good setup, git is quite powerful and immensely useful.

Comment: I edited the answer above to better try to answer your question regarding bare repo as central repo (which would be fine).